# UIActivityViewController whatsapp share dialog white text background

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp, uiactivitycontroller

I am using below code to share some content. When I choose whatsapp option, I am seeing white background behind the texts. I am totally lost because UIActivityController handles presenting the share dialog. Any idea how to remove the white background?

```
let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [text, url], applicationActivities: [])
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using ChameleonFramework? I've found that this changes the colours in the sharing panel.

Comment: No I dont use it. But same code works with other apps. There must be something that affects the whatsapp sharing dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, it looks like the WhatsApp interface is applying a white background colour to UILabels. You could give this a try:

```
let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [text, url], applicationActivities: [])
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIView.self]).backgroundColor = .clear
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: It gives the error: `Cannot convert value of type 'UIActivityViewController' to expected element type 'UIAppearanceContainer.Type'` but I tried `UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIActivityViewController.self]).backgroundColor = .clear` instead but no luck.

Comment: Sorry, you should give it an instance of UIView, not a view controller. Try:  `UIButton.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIView.self]).backgroundColor = .clear`

Comment: I am using transparent UITableViewCell background. probably that is the reason. your appraoch was correct. But Label appearance inside UITableViewCell could not be set. So I changed the UITableViewCell backgrund to white.  `UITableViewCell.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIView.self]).backgroundColor = .white`

Comment: Glad you've fixed it!